# Azure Monitoring - Alerts - Notification Status not set to "Subscribed"

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azureportal, azure-monitoring, azure-alerts

When I try to add a new email address to an existing action group (to receive notifications), I can't get the status 'Subscribed':

[image: Action group - Email Notification]

I believe this is the reason why the M user is receiving the alerts while the R and L users aren't.

I read in the following link that when the status is 'Unsubscribed', we should remove the email and then re-add it:

[Troubleshooting the Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-troubleshoot#did-not-receive-expected-email)

I did this, but it didn't fix it. That's probably because my status was never "Unsubscribed" in the first place, but instead "-".

Any ideas on what I should try next?

Comment: Yesterday, and without changing any configuration, the R and L users started receiving the alerts (even though the status is still set to '-'). I'm starting to think this might be some sort of Azure bug. I would like to add that I didn't change anything in my email config either.

Answer (score 0):

**I Tried to reproduce the same in my environment to delete the existing email from Action Group, As I got below.**

[image]

Note: `Subscribed status in action group ,you will get only for the first time, later if you modify emails in Action Group, you will get Same "-" status ,but mail will trigger.`

I have created one alert rule with action group like below.

**Azure Portal > Monitor > Create Alert Rule**

[image]

Once modify the email and save the configuration.

The movement you modify the settings, you will get the test mail from Microsoft Notification.